# convert accelerometer and gyroscope data from an Arduino into an iOS SCNNode position and rotation

Tags: swift, scenekit, accelerometer, gyroscope

**Context:**

- I have an Arduino Nano RP2040 Connect device which has a built-in
  IMU.
- I also have written an iOS app that utilizes SceneKit and can render/animate SCNNodes.

**Goal**

I want to move my Arduino around in real life and have a visualizer in SceneKit mirror those movements in virtual space.

**So far, I can**

1. access Arduino's IMU accelerometer and gyroscope values from the Arduino and pass them to my iOS app in real time.
2. render an SCNNode and animate updates to the position and rotation arbitrarily

**What's missing**

- I need to write the logic to convert the accelerometer and gyroscope vectors into position and rotation vectors.

I've attempted a couple different suggestions on how to do this, but the result is never correct. Can someone please help me with the code to make that work?

side note - I understand my Arduino and SceneKit coordinates work off of different axis, but the visualization I result in is not at all close to mirroring the Arduino so I feel I'm pretty far off the mark here so far.